# How to display category in wordpress in Select Box with different name

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to build a filter search option in wordpress by category base .

like :

Example : Category by Country

```
      category by City 

      Category by Street
```

and have submit button for search .

How can i display the category in a select box with different name of select box. any help.

Comment: I think you should provide some more info so that we would get a clear idea regarding your question!

Answer (score 0):

You could create this from scratch using jQuery/JSON to populate the categories on the fly but have a look at [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-ultimate-search/). It provides a out of the box solution and with some customisation, I am sure you can achive what you want!

Good luck!

Comment: How to display this plugin form in my theme. I installed but nothing show.

Comment: Add a shortcode to a post, use the template tag in your theme, or use the sidebar widget.
To use the shortcode: Place [wp-ultimate-search-bar] where you'd like the search bar, and [wp-ultimate-search-results] where you'd like the results.

To use the template tag: Put wp_ultimate_search_bar() where you'd like the search bar, and wp_ultimate_search_results() where you'd like the results.

Comment: <?php wp_ultimate_search_bar(); ?> Add that where you want it to display ;)

Answer (score -1):

Does `wp_dropdown_categories();` achieve the correct result?

[See Link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_categories)